# AWS AppStream is unable to push session script logs to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc, aws-ec2

I have configured session scripts to log stdout and stderr to s3 bucket as described  in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appstream2/latest/developerguide/use-session-scripts.html#enable-S3-bucket-storage-session-script-logs & https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appstream2/latest/developerguide/create-session-scripts.html .

The log files are created successfully on a running appstream instance at `/opt/appstream/SessionScripts/logs` , but they are not pushed to s3 buckets.

Based on the article above, we do not need to perform any additional settings to make this happen.

- I assigned a policy to the fleet that has full access to s3 (AmazonS3FullAccess).
- There is no error about permissions or failure etc logged in CloudWatch or in /var/logs/ on a running instance.

What could be causing this issue? Anything else to be checked?